Changing background color of inidividiual row (verticalHeader) labels in PyQt5 QTableView?
In my application, I would like to conditionally change the text and background color of arbitrary row labels (verticalHeader) of QTableView.
In the example below, to simplify things, all I'm trying to do is to change the row (verticalHeader) label of the second row (i.e. row with index or section 1) when the button is pressed - specifically to red text color and greenish background color.
As far as I'm aware, the way to do this in QTableView is from the headerData method, using the Qt.TextColorRole and Qt.BackgroundRole, which is what I did in in the example below. Upon application start, the following GUI state is rendered (on Windows 10, MINGW64 Python3 and PyQt5 libraries):

... but after I press the "Toggle row label indicate" button, I get this:

... where the headerData Qt.TextColorRole changes work (that is, the text color of the row label for the second row becomes red, as expected), but the Qt.BackgroundRole does not work  (the background color of the row label for the second row does not change).
So, what am I doing wrong, and how can I get the background color of the row label for the second row changed (hopefully, without having to write a new QHeaderView class)?
This seems to have been a long-standing question (e.g. https://forum.qt.io/topic/28279 from 2013), but I've never found anything with a simple, minimal reproducible example of the problem - and no solutions either - so I thought it was worth it asking again.
The post How to control header background color in a table view with model? simply suggests using QCSS; however if you uncomment the line self.table_view.setStyleSheet(table_view_qcss) in the example below, it is visible that QCSS changes all header labels - and the exact same behavior is reproduced upon button press, just with gray header labels as a starting point; so, after button press, the GUI state rendered is this:

... that is, again, headerData Qt.TextColorRole changes work, Qt.BackgroundRole does not work.
I have noted that https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html states:

Not all ItemDataRoles will have an effect on a QHeaderView. If you need to draw other roles, you can subclass QHeaderView and reimplement paintEvent(). QHeaderView respects the following item data roles, ...:
TextAlignmentRole, DisplayRole, FontRole, DecorationRole, ForegroundRole, and BackgroundRole.

... which strongly suggests Qt.BackgroundRole should have worked; however there is also the part left out in the quote above:

... unless they are in conflict with the style (which can happen for styles that follow the desktop theme)

... which then implies why Qt.BackgroundRole might fail to perform.
So, I found Qt::BackgroundRole seems to be ignored, where an answer hints at the following as solution:


For specific table or header view, use style that respects brushes:
//auto keys = QStyleFactory::keys();
if(auto style = QStyleFactory::create("Fusion")) {
verticalHeader()->setStyle(style);
}



Something similar is also mentioned in https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/13094-QTableView-headerData()-color :

The header doesn't use the delegate. It's a very limited class, so if you want something fancy, you'll have to subclass QHeaderView and implement it yourself. ...
Qt tries to follow the platform style. If Windows doesn't allow header colours to be modified, they won't be. You could run your application with a different style (using -style stylename switch, i.e. -style plastique) on Windows and it'll probably work then. ...
You can "cheat" even more by changing the style of the header only and leaving the rest of the application running the default style. That's how stylesheets work, by the way...

... but you can see that in my example, I've tried doing self.table_view.verticalHeader().setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion")), and it seems to make no difference (headerData Qt.BackgroundRole still fails to change the target row label background color).
The same answer in Qt::BackgroundRole seems to be ignored also mentions:


You can also achieve it by using own item delegates - inherit from QStyledItemDelegate or whatever else, reimplement one method and set it to view.


... but then, I see in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html:

Note: Each header renders the data for each section itself, and does not rely on a delegate. As a result, calling a header's setItemDelegate() function will have no effect.

... so now I really don't know what to think anymore ...
So, is there any way to get a PyQt5 QTableView background color of arbitrary row labels changed, using headerData and Qt.BackgroundRole?
Here is the example code:
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPointF)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor, QPalette, QPixmap, QBrush, QPen, QPainter)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QStyleFactory)
# starting point from https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qtableview-modelviews-numpy-pandas/

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parview):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self._parview = parview # parent table view
    #
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)
    #
    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data[0])
    #
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:     # https://stackoverflow.com/q/57321588
            return QColor("#AA{:02X}{:02X}".format(
              index.row()*20+100, index.column()*20+100
            ))
    #
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole): # https://stackoverflow.com/q/64287713
        if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            if role == Qt.TextColorRole:
                # only for the second row, where section == 1
                if (section == 1) and (self._parview.rowLabelIndicate):
                    return QColor("red")
            if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
                # only for the second row, where section == 1
                if (section == 1) and (self._parview.rowLabelIndicate):
                    return QColor("#88FF88") #QBrush(QColor("#88FF88"))
        #
        # without the super call, no text is printed on header view labels!
        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralw = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralw)
        self.vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralw)
        #
        self.btn = QPushButton("Toggle row label indicate")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.toggleRowLabelIndicate)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.btn)
        #
        self.table_view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table_view.rowLabelIndicate = False # dynamically added attribute/property
        print(f"{QStyleFactory.keys()=}") # for me, it is: ['windowsvista', 'Windows', 'Fusion']
        self.table_view.verticalHeader().setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion")) # passes here, no crash!
        self.table_view.verticalHeader().setMinimumWidth(28) # int; seems to be in pixels
        table_view_qcss = "QHeaderView::section { background-color:#DDDDDD }"
        #self.table_view.setStyleSheet(table_view_qcss)
        data = [
          [ 1, 2, 3 ],
          [ "hello", "world", "42" ],
          [ 4, "more", "words" ],
        ]
        self.model = TableModel(data, self.table_view)
        self.table_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.table_view)
        #
        self.resizeToContents()
    #
    def resizeToContents(self):
        self.table_view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.table_view.resizeRowsToContents()
    #
    def toggleRowLabelIndicate(self):
      self.table_view.rowLabelIndicate = not(self.table_view.rowLabelIndicate)
      change_row_start = change_row_end = 1
      self.model.headerDataChanged.emit(Qt.Vertical, change_row_start, change_row_end)

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
window.resize(180, 160)
app.exec_()


Setting a compliant style (notably, Fusion, as all Windows styles ignore header background roles) is the only simple way to achieve that. Your code is correct, but you need to properly update the header. Add self.table_view.verticalHeader().viewport().update() to toggleRowLabelIndicate().

Many thanks @musicamante - unfortunately, self.table_view.verticalHeader().viewport().update() was not the solution here, however it lead me to find the solution - assigning the output of QStyleFactory.create to a class property, before using in setStyle - which I documented in the answer below.

Ok, arrived at a solution: first I tried adding self.table_view.verticalHeader().viewport().update() to toggleRowLabelIndicate(), as suggested by @musicamante in comment; however, the background color of the target row label still did not change upon button press.
Then I thought, maybe I need to delay the .viewport().update(), so I tried running it via QTimer.singleShot - nope, that did not work either.
Then I tried the script on Ubuntu as well - nope, that did not work either.
And after a few other desperate attempts, I finally noticed that the line that sets the style for the vertical header is:
        self.table_view.verticalHeader().setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion")) # passes here, no crash!

... and I recalled that I've had situations in my previous experience, that if I use a return of a function directly as an argument of another function, sometimes the "reference" to this returns gets somehow "lost" - so the question was how to confirm that this is the problem.
It turns out, the return of QStyleFactory.create is a QCommonStyle object, which has an .objectName() method - and luckily, in this case outputs the name of the style; so when I printed self.table_view.verticalHeader().style().objectName() right after the setStyle call, I could see it was gtk2 (on Ubuntu), which meant that whatever change of style I wanted to do with setStyle did not go through (probably because the reference to the returned QCommonStyle object got "lost").
So, the solution was to first run QStyleFactory.create as a separate step and assign it as a class MainWindow object property (so the reference does not get lost) - and then use this object propert as argument of setStyle; and indeed, things started working after that change: for instance, here is the GUI after press of button:

... and we can see the expected greenish background on the row label of the second row; and this is also supported by the printout of the fixed example script included below:
QStyleFactory.keys()=['windowsvista', 'Windows', 'Fusion']
self.qsf_fusion=<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCommonStyle object at 0x00000287c3501f30>
self.table_view.verticalHeader().style().objectName()='fusion'

... as now we can see that after setStyle, the verticalHeader().style().objectName() returns 'fusion', as expected.
However, note that now the verticalHeader labels have a slightly different style from the horizontal ones - this is maybe more obvious on Ubuntu with gtk2 default theme, where it follows the dark mode of the OS:

So then, this means that if you want both your horizontal and vertical header labels with consistent styling in this case, you must now also change the horizontal header style as well, and possibly more work needs to be done to keep everything consistent via BackgroundRole.
Anyways - once that setStyle is called with an object property as argument and things start working, it turns out self.table_view.verticalHeader().viewport().update() is not really needed, for the background color change of the target row label to work upon button press.
This is the final version of the code that worked for me:
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPointF, QTimer)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor, QPalette, QPixmap, QBrush, QPen, QPainter)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QStyleFactory)
# starting point from https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qtableview-modelviews-numpy-pandas/

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parview):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self._parview = parview # parent table view
    #
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)
    #
    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data[0])
    #
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:     # https://stackoverflow.com/q/57321588
            return QColor("#AA{:02X}{:02X}".format(
              index.row()*20+100, index.column()*20+100
            ))
    #
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole): # https://stackoverflow.com/q/64287713
        if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            if role == Qt.TextColorRole:
                # only for the second row, where section == 1
                if (section == 1) and (self._parview.rowLabelIndicate):
                    return QColor("red")
            if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
                # only for the second row, where section == 1
                if (section == 1) and (self._parview.rowLabelIndicate):
                    return QColor("#88FF88") #QBrush(QColor("#88FF88"))
        #
        # without the super call, no text is printed on header view labels!
        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralw = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralw)
        self.vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralw)
        #
        self.btn = QPushButton("Toggle row label indicate")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.toggleRowLabelIndicate)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.btn)
        #
        self.table_view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table_view.rowLabelIndicate = False # dynamically added attribute/property
        print(f"{QStyleFactory.keys()=}") # for me, it is: ['windowsvista', 'Windows', 'Fusion'] (on Ubuntu: ['gtk2', 'Windows', 'Fusion'])
        #self.table_view.verticalHeader().setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion")) # passes here, no crash! however, reference to return of .create seems to get lost, and style does not really get changed!
        self.qsf_fusion = QStyleFactory.create("Fusion") # dynamically added attribute/property
        print(f"{self.qsf_fusion=}")
        self.table_view.verticalHeader().setStyle(self.qsf_fusion) # passes here, no crash!
        print(f"{self.table_view.verticalHeader().style().objectName()=}") # still 'gtk2', unless we use self.qsf_fusion!
        self.table_view.verticalHeader().setMinimumWidth(28) # int; seems to be in pixels
        table_view_qcss = "QHeaderView::section { background-color:#DDDDDD }"
        #self.table_view.setStyleSheet(table_view_qcss) # on Ubuntu with 'gtk2' style default, and self.qsf_fusion applied as above, enabling this line will make only the verticalHeader painted with gray background; on Windows with 'windowsvista' style default, both horizontal and vertical Header will have gray background - and of course, for both OSs, using QCSS will prevent the BackgroundRole from working
        data = [
          [ 1, 2, 3 ],
          [ "hello", "world", "42" ],
          [ 4, "more", "words" ],
        ]
        self.model = TableModel(data, self.table_view)
        self.table_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.table_view)
        #
        self.resizeToContents()
    #
    def resizeToContents(self):
        self.table_view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.table_view.resizeRowsToContents()
    #
    def toggleRowLabelIndicate(self):
      self.table_view.rowLabelIndicate = not(self.table_view.rowLabelIndicate)
      change_row_start = change_row_end = 1
      self.model.headerDataChanged.emit(Qt.Vertical, change_row_start, change_row_end)
      #self.table_view.verticalHeader().viewport().update() # no need
      #QTimer.singleShot(100, self.table_view.verticalHeader().viewport().update)

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
window.resize(180, 160)
app.exec_()


Printing the style object always returns QCommonStyle, because that's the base class from which most styles inherit: even the basic Fusion and Windows styles (the only ones available by default) will still print a QCommonStyle, because their classes are private: PyQt can only expose class names it knows about (Qt public classes), and the only way to eventually retrieve internal class names is by going through the QMetaObject interface. That said, it seems strange that, even after applying the style through QStyleFactory, you get a different style, unless the default style does that on its own.
